# What is the reason of using different names for the same table or array?

Tags: names, maple

Usually when I do `b:=a` I expect to have a copy of `a`, so that changing `b` won't change `a`, for example:

```
a:=[1,2,3]; b:=a: b[1]:=5: a;
                            a := [1, 2, 3]
                              [1, 2, 3]
```

But in case of tables or rtables (Array, Vector, Matrix) that's not the case:

```
a:=Array([1,2,3]); b:=a: b[1]:=5: a;
                            a := [1, 2, 3]
                              [5, 2, 3]
```

I know that I can use [copy](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=copy) command to solve this problem, but I'm curious where the latter behavior is needed? I'd like to see an example.

Answer (score 1):

The latter types are mutable, and can be passed to procedures by reference and hence changed within a procedure.

A Maple list is not mutable and so "copying" a list as you are always creates a new list. This "value-like" behaviour is often of convenience, but can be troublesome if using a list to store scaling numbers of expressions.